# Adding tooltip to disabled Dropdown.Toggle

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

If `Dropdown.Toggle` is not disabled tooltip works. When `Dropdown.Toggle` has the class

```
.disabled {
     pointer-events: none;
}.
```

Tooltip does not work.
I'm using the library: `react-bootstrap` and`react-tooltip`.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tnh9rr

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      disabled: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown className = {`${this.state.disabled  ? 'disabled' :     null}`} onClick={this.checkStatus}>
        <Dropdown.Toggle  data-tip="hello world" variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
            Change status
        <ReactTooltip/>
        </Dropdown.Toggle>
        <Dropdown.Menu >
            <Dropdown.Item>AAAAAAA</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check the state property(`disabled`) when the particular function is called with `onClick` event on `Dropdown` component.`pointer-events: none` disables all the mouse events and hence we are unable to see the `tooltip` as tooltip mostly gets triggered when you `hover` it on the `button` and since `hover` is also a kind of event in mouse no event is triggered
.

Comment: I don't see any tooltip

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events please go though this explanation about `pointer-events: none`